# C++ QAbstractListModel server side, QML ListView client side

Tags: listview, qml, client-server, qabstractlistmodel

I create a client/server application in which I load the qml files on the client from the server with something like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath("http://127.0.0.1/qmldir"); //127.... to test locally
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

In one qml file, I have a ListView which model has to be created from a C++ class, which inherits from QAbstractListModel, and above all, which is on the server side of the application (the client only has qml file for interface).

So I would like to use a QAbstractListModel as I want to use the ListView "normally" that's to say click on an item of the list, when I drag the list to display the next or previous items, the list is updated, ..., as if it wasn't a client/server application.
I have something like:

Client side, qml for the interface:

```
MyModel{
    id:myModel
}

ListView{
    id:listView
    model: myModel
    ...
}
```

C++ class on the server:

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    ...
}
```

So I wonder how to connect those two elements, if it's possible or not? Or what is the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK a proxy on client side is necessary. This proxy receives the RPCs from Server and interacts with the Qml GUI. The events from Qml are handled by proxy and sent back to server. I don't know whether there is any proxy generator with focus on Qt.

Comment: There's https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html

Comment: @GrecKo: I have no experience with that, but the documentation looks like you can only gain access to signals, slots and properties. I think for a model to work, you need to gain access to the full `QAbstractItemModel`-API, don't you? Is that possible with those remote objects?